# State in Angular2 service not updated by ngrx/store

Tags: ngrx

I'm having this reducer:

*heroStore.reducer.ts*

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import {Hero} from '../models/hero';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export const UPDATE = '[hero] UPDATE';

export function heroReducer(state: { [heroId: string]: BehaviorSubject<Hero>; } = {}, action: Action):
{ [heroId: string]: BehaviorSubject<Hero>; } {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE:
      let newState;
      const hero: Hero = action.payload;
      if (state[hero.uid]) { // hero exists
        newState = state[hero.uid].next(hero);
      } else {
        const heroObservable = new BehaviorSubject<Hero>(hero);
        newState = Object.assign({}, state, {[hero.uid]: heroObservable});
      }
      console.log('New State', newState);
      return newState;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and the following service

*hero.service.ts*

```
getHero(heroId: string): BehaviorSubject<Hero> {
  let state;
  this.store.select('heroStore').subscribe(s => state = s);
  console.log('state returned in service', state);
  return state[heroId];
}
```

And finally the following test:

```
  it('should be able to get a hero', inject([HeroService], (service: HeroService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();

    heroReducer({}, {
      type: '[hero] UPDATE',
      payload: {
        uid: '5',
        name: 'Franz'
      }
    });

    const heroObs = service.getHero('5');
    expect(heroObs.getValue().name).toEqual('Franz');

  }));
```

But somehow the state doesn't get updated. It produces the following logs:

> LOG: 'New State', Object{5: BehaviorSubject{_isScalar: false,
>   observers: [], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false,
>   thrownError: null, _value: Object{uid: ..., name: ...}}}
>
> LOG: 'state returned in service', Object{}

So the reducer actually returns the correct new state. But when subscribed upon in the service, I still get an empty object.

If I understand correctly, a store in ngrx/store is a rxjs BehaviorSubject, which in turn is supposed to return the **last** value on subscription. From the docs of BehaviorSubject:

> Observers can subscribe to the subject to receive the last (or initial) value and all subsequent notifications

**So how is it possible that state is still an empty object?**

Answer (score -1):

Your `getHero` is not coded properly and I think it returns an unassigned value. A better way to write it would be:

```
getHero(heroId: string): BehaviorSubject<Hero> {
  let state = new BehaviorSubject<Hero>();
  this.store.select('heroStore').subscribe(s => state.next(s[heroId]));
  return state;
}
```

or even better:

```
getHero(heroId: string): Observable<Heor> {
    return this.store.select('heroStore')
        .map(heros => heros[heroId];
}
```

or if you want to really go elegant, this might work:

```
getHero(heroId: string): Observable<Heor> {
    return this.store.select('heroStore', heroId);
}
```

Comment: 1) In your first option, you create a new behaviorSubject on each retrieval 2) could you point out the problem in my code more specifically? 3) your second option returns Observable<{ [heroId: string]: BehaviorSubject<Hero>; }> if I'm not mistaken. 4) how would your 3rd option do what I want?

Comment: In the first one I tried to stay close to your code, and although you create a new subject, if you unsubscribe it will not cause a problem. Keeping a global subject might case future requests to provide out of date (=previous data).
The select can do a drill down so if you provide multiple params it drills down the result. The first one will get the heroStore, the second one will get the specific field. 
As for your code. The select is async, hence the assignment state = s might be called after you return and use the value so in practice when you do return state[heroId], state is still null

Comment: state isn't undefined, it's {} as you can see in the logs i've posted. And according to the ngrx/store docs, the store is a BehaviorSubject, so it returns a value immediately upon subscription.

Comment: But that's the initial value, isn't it? You probably want the updated value. Anyways, rxjs wise this doesn't seem right.

Comment: I understood it's the last value, not the initial one. From the docs of BehaviorSubject: "Observers can subscribe to the subject to receive the last (or initial) value and all subsequent notifications"

Comment: Yes, yet, it is an async action. You can't mix them. Async question might be immediate in some cases, but in others invoked after the current stack is cleared.